# Django 1.3 fixtures for a specific app

Tags: django

Am wanting to dump data to a json from Django 1.3 fixtures using the following but the result is an empty list. Anything that am doing wrong here?

```
python manage.py dumpdata <app-name> --format=json --indent 5 > C:\temp\tt.json
```

Edit: The app of interest is not the default database alias. Am able to successfully use `dumpdata` for default database alias with/without mentioning the `<app-name>` but unable for other databases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New in Django 1.2 is a common `--database` option for all manage.py commands. You can use an '=' or a space in that. So give this a try:

```
python manage.py dumpdata <app-name> --database <other_db> --format=json --indent 5 > C:\temp\tt.json
```

Also, I've found a more flexible solution to dumpdata. For one, dumpdata ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model)) can be confusing if you have custom managers on your model though this straightened out a little bit with Django 1.3's `--all` option. For two, dumpdata doesn't order its output and that annoys me when I want clean, shining fixture data. Or say you only want some of the model data dumped/exported. Instead I use Django [Serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/). This allows me to pick out *whatever* data I want with normal Querysets - filtered, ordered, exluded, etc - and then serialize it to JSON (or XML). Example:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> from <your project>.<app>.models import MyModel
>>> serializers.serialize('json', MyModel.objects.all().order_by('name'), use_natural_keys=True)
```

Then reformat in a text editor and paste into a fixtures file.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `--indent=5` not `--indent 5`. Not sure if that's your problem, but worth trying.

Also, FWIW, JSON is the default, so `--format=json` is unnecessary.

Comment: Actually, just tested that and the missing `=` doesn't cause a problem after all. What you have should work. Are you sure there's actually data?

Comment: Yes there is data. <model-name>.objects.all() brings back results!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try this:

```
python manage.py dumpdata <app-name>
```

if You see same data in the output, the the second one should work!

after, try this out:

```
python manage.py dumpdata <app-name> --indent 2 > C:\temp\tt.json
```

HOWEVER make sure that  it is in your settings.INSTALLED_APPS and also it has the exactly same name!